# How to display a character in the wrong characterset

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, mojibake

How can I output whatever `æ` would be, if `ø = Ã¸`?

I'm guessing the left side is unicode and the right side is something else, for example iso-8859-1, but how can I print out what a unicode character would be when messed up?

---

**Backstory**: I have a bit of a strange problem here with Steam messing up character encodings. Trying to help a friend recover their account and I think they have used the letter `æ` in their secret answer. The dialog for resetting the password doesn't accept that letter, and it says the answer is wrong if we try natural alternatives. In the recovery email I get, the letter `ø` shows up as `Ã¸` in the secret question. So, I'm thinking perhaps when the answer and question was created, the letter `æ` was accepted, but messed up. Figured I could try to use the messed up equivalent, but don't know what that would be, and my programming skills fails me in finding it myself :p

Comment: It seemslike your problem would be most easily resolved by contacting Steam's customer service.

Comment: That particular case, probably yes. But I got curious from a developers perspective here. Irregardless of if it solves the problem, I'm curious to how I could do this with programming :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can encode the string to a byte-string in UTF-8, and then convert the byte-string to a (text) string using iso-8859-1. The result will be the desired [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

In Python 3:

```
>>> 'æ'
'æ'
>>> 'æ'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc3\xa6'
>>> 'æ'.encode('utf8').decode('iso-8859-1')
'Ã¦'
```

In Python 2, use `u'æ'` instead of `'æ'`.